# How to call another "new" route in camel

Tags: apache-camel

I have a route (A) that do some stuff like calling a REST service.

In this route, before calling the REST service, I need to call another REST service, to valorize some data in my app. That new call is in another route (B).

I'm searching for tips to call that second route (B), but with a new "Exchange" (I want no link between exchange in A and B).

```
 from(ROUTE_A)
        .routeId(ROUTE_A)
        .process(someProcessA())
        //I need to call the route B here, but without giving in the current exchange content
        //Route A must wait until before route B execution is complete
        .process(someProcessB())
        .to(http://blahblah.com/)
        .end()
```

Does anyone know a solution ?

Thanks,

Comment: It would be better if you put some code snippets.

Comment: Please show your route configuration. It's hard to suggest anything without seeing your current routes.

Comment: Sorry, updated.

Comment: You can call other routes via direct endpoints, eg to direct:foo and have a route that starts with from direct:foo

Comment: Yep, I found it. But I want to call another route, who do some stuff independantly.. (e.g. the body of A and B routes are independent)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the [content-enricher](http://people.apache.org/~dkulp/camel/content-enricher.html) EIP would help

Comment: I don't want to modify the current body, I want to call another route, who do some stuff independantly...

Comment: si multicast should be what you are looking fot